# How can I get a file's last modified time in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, file, time

I need to find the **time** when the file was last modified in a day.

Using the below code I only get the **date**:

```
System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath("myFile.txt")).ToString("D");
```

How to get only the time part?

Answer (score 6):

Use HH, mm, ss:

```
System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath("myFile.txt")).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score -1):

May be this will help:

```
 System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\MyPath\a.txt").TimeOfDay.ToString()
```

I go this:

```
17:55:14.3229896
```

You can format as per your convenience